# Immutable.js .map return multiple elements on one iteration

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am trying to use Immutable's [.map()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/map) to iterate over a `List()` of "segments".

Each segment may span multiple days, if so I would like to break this segment up into multiple segments, each which span only one day.

I seem to have the basic logic working:

```
const segmentedList = nonSegmentedList.map((segment) => {
  if (spansMultipleDays(segment)) {
    return segmentByDay(segment) // returns a list
  } else {
    return segment
  }
})
return segmentedList
```

My issue is that `.map`'s return will return a List of segments, and populate them in a single `segmentedList` List item. For example, say segment1 and segment3 span one day, while "segment2" spans three days.

My return value would look something like this:

```
[
  {segment1},
  [{segment2a}, {segment2b}, {segment2c}],
  {segment3}
]
```

However, this is what is desired:

```
[
  {segment1},
  {segment2a},
  {segment2b},
  {segment2c},
  {segment3}
]
```

[Immutable's flatMap](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/flatMap) function kind of sounds like what I'm looking for, but replacing .map in the above snippet with flatMap yielded the same results.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to simply [`flatten()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/flatten) the collection and then map it.

```js
const collection = Immutable.fromJS([1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6])
collection.flatten().map(item => console.log(item))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immutable"></script>
```